# How to ascribe the value count of a list item to a new column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, count

Imagine that I have a dataset `df` with one column containing a dictionary with two list types (`list_A` and `list_B`) as value:

```
data = [{"list_A": [2.93, 4.18, 4.18, None, 1.57, 1.57, 3.92, 6.27, 2.09, 3.14, 0.42, 2.09],
         "list_B": [820, 3552, 7936, None, 2514, 4035, 6441, 15379, 2167, 6147, 3322, 1177]},
        {"list_A": [2.51, 3.58, 3.58, None, 1.34, 1.34, 3.36, 5.37, 1.79, 2.69, 0.36, 1.79],
         "list_B": [820, 3552, 7936, None, 2514, 4035, 6441, 15379, 2167, 6147, 3322, 1177]},
        {"list_A": [None, 5.94, 5.94, None, 2.23, 2.23, 5.57, 8.9, 2.97, 4.45, 0.59, 2.97],
         "list_B": [820, 3552, 7936, None, 2514, 4035, 6441, 15379, 2167, 6147, 3322, 1177]}]

# Create a DataFrame with a column named "column_dic"
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_dic": [data]})
```

Now, I want to create an additional column `count_first_item` that contains the count of non-Null values of the first item ([0]) of the lists that correspond to "List_A".

The expected output of this is 2 (2.93 = +1; 2.51 = +1; None = 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for get first values of `list_A`, test non missing values by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
df['count_first_item'] = [pd.notna([y['list_A'][0] for y in x]).sum() 
                          for x in df['column_dic']]
print (df)
                                          column_dic  count_first_item
0  [{'list_A': [2.93, 4.18, 4.18, None, 1.57, 1.5...                 2
```

Or use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), get values of lists by `str` or [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html), get first values by indexing - `str[0]` and count non missing values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html):

```
df['count_first_item'] = (df['column_dic'].explode().str.get('list_A').str[0]
                                          .groupby(level=0).count())
print (df)
                                          column_dic  count_first_item
0  [{'list_A': [2.93, 4.18, 4.18, None, 1.57, 1.5...                 2
```

Comment: I used only one row in my example. I also have a dataset in which I have multiple rows with such dictionary values. The value of count_first_item should be 2 right?

Comment: @FoekeBoersma - DataFrame is different? Like `df = pd.DataFrame({"column_dic": [data]})` ?

Comment: @jazrael, indeed, I'll edit the question to match your suggestion